# How do I write a basic .sty to call a custom Type 1 font I have installed?

Tags: fonts, package-writing

I have installed several custom Type 1 fonts for use with `pdflatex`. The fonts work normally if I call them with

```
\renewcommand{\<rmdefault/sfdefault/ttdefault/etc>}{<fontname>}
```

I followed Karl Berry's scheme for naming the fonts, and now I am starting to get lost with so many abbreviations (a lot of three-letter names which aren't always obvious). So, I would like to write some .sty files with which I could call my fonts with a simpler and more descriptive `\usepackage{<longfontname>}`. I kindly ask for directions for writing a basic template for calling the font definition and, if possible/worth, parsing simple options (scaling, for instance).

Comment: Note that there is really nothing specific to fonts in this. It is just like writing any other package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to look at the files for similar fonts installed with your TeX distribution and/or follow the instructions in the Font Installation Guide, which also provides examples.

Here's the `.sty` file I wrote for the `romande` package which supports RomandeADF. This is not the simplest possible case because you asked about handling options, but it only handles one option and so is relatively simple. The fonts installed all use the Berry naming scheme. In this case, the vendor is `y` and the family is `rd`. `a` is alternate, as you presumably know.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{romande}[2010/06/27 v2.1 romande]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{nfssext-cfr}
%:boolkey for alternative encoding as default
\define@boolkey{romande.sty}[romande@]{alt}[true]{%
        \relax}
%:defaults to ensure everything is defined to something
\ExecuteOptionsX{alt=false}
%:options override defaults
\ProcessOptionsX
%:make RomandeADF default roman font, implementing option for alternative encoding as applicable
\ifromande@alt
        \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{yrda}%
\else
        \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{yrd}%
\fi
\endinput
%% end romande.sty
```

If your fonts are named according to the Berry scheme and you need access to non-standard shapes, weights, widths etc., then `nfssext-cfr` may be helpful, as it is for Romande. This is an extension of `nfssext`, supplied as part of the Font Installation Guide.

Note that scaling requires that you configured the `.fd` files to accommodate this option. (Just as the `alt` option supported by `romande` relies on the `.fd` files being configured in a certain way.)

## EDIT

Regarding option support ....

You set a package option to do something. For example, in this case, `romande.sty` offers two distinct font families.

- The default is the non-alternate: `t1yrd.fd` and `ts1yrd.fd` support this option.
- The alternate family has slightly different glyphs in some slots and is supported by `t1yrda.fd` and `ts1yrda.fd`.

The alternate glyphs can also be accessed using macros from `nfssext-cfr`.

In addition, there are some other `.fd` files which aren't supported by package options: `t1yrdw.fd`, `ts1yrdw.fd`, `t1yrdaw.fd`, `ts1yrdaw.fd`. These support some fancier glyphs as 'swash' characters. ('Swash' maybe misleading, but they have to be classified as something.) These families are accessible through macros provided by `nfssext-cfr`.

If you installed the fonts, you should know what the `.fd` files support. It is then a question of deciding whether it makes sense to choose between different options on package loading or in some other way. In some cases, either option would be reasonable. For something like scaling, that only really makes sense as either a package option. That is, it should be constant for the entire document.

If you have set the fonts up to support scaling, then the `.fd` files should include lines like this one from `t1phv.fd` in the `psnfss` package:

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{phv}{m}{n}{
   <-> \Hv@@scale phvr8t
}{}
```

as opposed to lines like this one from `t1yrd.fd`:

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{yrd}{m}{n}{
   <-> yrdr8t
}{}
```

This shows that the `psnfss` support for Helvetica supports scaling the fonts, whereas `romande`'s support for Romande does not.

Comment: That's great! Without any option parsing, it works like a charm. I did not try to set options yet: is there some way for me to know if my .fd files allow setting any options? Thanks!

Comment: Please see edit. It got too long for a comment.